# Can we count remaining LinkedIn daily API calls?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm familiar with the daily limit of API calls that LinkedIn has. Is there a way that we can count the remaining calls for current day? I don't want to get in situation when my app will exceed the number of calls (if limit is 500, my call with #501 will throw an error).

Is there a way to check this before making a certain call? That will be very helpful for protection of exceeding the number of daily API calls.

Comment: Regardless of this, your app should implement error handling - it could be that LinkedIn is not available or else. Also, please tell me more about the app. Can u use a database or else to count our daily calls?

Comment: Yes I can use DB for counting. I was thinking that maybe there is some web request that returns number of calls so that I can save processing time.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of your applications at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer you can see on the right of every application a link to "View API Usage" click it and you'll see all kinds of information about the calls you made and if they exceed maximum.

But I don't think there's any call to know it apart from that link.